# Bare minimum needed to make 'import ODBC.Windows' work in Python

Tags: python, odbc

I have inherited some legacy code, and at this point I just need to get it working - only it has this code:

```
import ODBC.Windows, os
DBconn = ODBC.Windows.connect("DRG3","sa","")
cursor = DBconn.cursor()
```

I have added pyODBC, pyWin32, and mxODBC to my Python 2.7 installation, still nothing worked. This seems to be mxODBC code, but their installation instructions are vague and it seems like a paid product now (though it probably was not when this was written, circa 2001). Even after the installation, there was no change until I copied relevant files from Python27\Lib\site-packages\mx\mxODBC\ to Python27\Lib, and even after repeatedly hunting the required files for this and adding them to \Lib, I finally get to 'No module named Windows'.

The bottom line is, I want this to connect with the least amount of effort so I can move on. I've never used python before, so I'd appreciate any help. I'm not committed to using mxODBC, but I'd need to know what to change the code to if I was using something else.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm sorry this has to be your introduction to Python. Being thrown in at the deep end is no fun. Having said that, I have some remarks which I hope will prove helpful.

1. The program you're trying to get to run is *old*. You mentioned the year 2001 (which in my mind conjures up images of stone-age people) so this would be Python 2.0 or 2.1. Now, I'm not too concerned about the language itself, as keeping the core language and standard libraries backwards compatible is a major priority for the maintainers, but that might not be the case for any other libraries the application needs. APIs can change a lot in 11 years, and some libraries may be abandoned altogether (which probably means that there are better alternatives, but still). All I'm saying here is that you'll *probably* need to be patient here.
2. If this program really uses mxODBC as its database connector (and it certainly looks that way) please be advised that it it has some dependencies of its own. (See the [Egenix](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxODBC/) site). By the way, as far as I know, mxODBC has always been a commercial product, although the exact licensing may have changed.
3. Also, I *think* the import statement should read:

   ```
   import mx.ODBC.Windows, os
   ```

   Which means the connect statement should read:

   ```
   mx.ODBC.Windows.connect("DRG3","sa","")
   ```
4. Moving Python files around in the \Lib directory like you did might have broken things. You probably want to undo that.
5. I'm also a bit concerned about the datasource you want to connect to. If its really ODBC you might have problems setting that up or getting that to work, but it depends on what flavour of Windows you're running under. For a long time Microsoft have been deprecating ODBC, and 64 bit Windows really broke stuff here. Recently, it would seem, they have gone back on that, but I'm unsure what, exactly, that resulted in so far.
6. If for some reason mxODBC doesn't work for you, try **pyodbc**. You'd need to construct a proper connection string for that to work, but there are enough examples floating around the internet to get you started.

I'd personally go for the last option in the list, but that is just because I have had some good experiences with pyodbc, and no experience at all with mxODBC. Like the saying goes: your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this with pyodbc:

```
import pyodbc
DBconn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=DRG3;UID=sa;PWD=")
cursor = DBconn.cursor()
```